# What determines the assembly identity for ngen lookup?

Tags: .net, ngen

How does ngen lookup native images?

**Example 1:**

I compile MyApp.exe v1.0.0.0  in C:\Test\MyApp\bin\Debug\MyApp.exe . 
I ngen MyApp.exe via `ngen install MyApp.exe`. After this `ngen display MyApp` will tell me that I have an NGen root at the full path to the executable. `ngen display MyApp.exe` in the directory will also tell me this particular file installed. Next, I change something in my app and recompile it *without changing the version*. Doing ngen display for the exe tells me it is NOT installed (which is nice) but why? Is the hash directory that ngen stores the MyApp.ni.exe under based on the file *contents*?

**Example 2:**

I compile the exe as in example 1, but then I move it to C:\Temp\MyApp.exe, and run `ngen display MyApp.exe`. Ngen will tell me this exe is *not* installed, but why? Is the lookup also based on an absolute path to the assembly file?

It seems like ngen computes a hash for lookup such as e.g. `ComputeHash(assemblyQualifiedName, assemblyFileChecksum, assemblyFullPath)`, is this correct?

Comment: Sure.  You can't get an accurate answer, it is undocumented and source has never been published.  But it is clear from [this blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/johnls/2005/08/13/changing-mvids/) that the MVID plays a key role in generating the hash.  [More here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/abhinaba/2013/12/11/net-loading-native-ngen-images-and-its-interaction-with-the-gac/).

Comment: Thanks. That raises some questions about what happens in reproducible builds, so I googled reproducible builds and MVID and found this which outlines the MVID generation with reproducible (basically just a SHA1) https://blog.paranoidcoding.com/2016/04/05/deterministic-builds-in-roslyn.html
The full paths thing still puzzles me though.